# Monitoring/protecting GoogleAds

Tags: google-adsense, protection, fraud-detection

How do you monitor who has clicked an advert and what is possible in terms of protecting against abusive clicks?

Comment: I've answered the second part of your question. What do you mean by monitoring who has clicked? Do you want their IP address?

Comment: @paulmorriss: IP address will do. I need to either block an IP and/or see which member of a site is clicking.

Comment: By "member of a site" do you mean which logged in user?

Comment: I mean any logged in user. The way I'd do things is to get an IP and check it against the IPs of the users. That way I can contact a person directly.

Answer (score 1):

Google try to detect and protect against click fraud themselves:
http://adwords.blogspot.com/2006/03/about-invalid-clicks.html

> Fighting invalid clicks aggressively
>   is in Google's best interest and
>   essential for us to maintain a viable
>   business.

There's more information here:
http://www.google.com/adwords/adtrafficquality/overview.html

Comment: This is why they deactivate accounts. What would be ideal to know in advance that click fraud is happening to avoid deactivation. For example, there is click bombing which is purposefully triggering clicks in order to have someone else's account taken down.

Comment: At the bottom of that overview page is a list of things you can do, including reporting that will help. Then you can report suspicious users: http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=165472&rd=1

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately Google have decided they won't reinstate the account so perhaps this question is moot. I could try to create another account but the chances are that it will probably be also deactivated.

Comment: Hi again. Having learned some jQuery it appears possible to intercept clicks to any html element. To anyone looking to detect clicks on an advert and blocking itif necessary, I suggest using this approach.